# How can I find multiple of the same format in Python?

Tags: python, regex

For a little idea of what the project is, I'm trying to make a markup language that compiles to HTML/CSS. I plan on formatting links like this: @(link mask)[(link url)], and I want to find all occurrences of this and get both the link mask and the link url.

I tried using this code for it:

```
re.search("@(.*)\[(.*)\]", string)
```

But it started at the beginning of the first instance, and ended at the end of the last instance of a link. Any ideas how I can have it find all of them, in a list or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of a regular expression is "greedy matching". This means each `.*` will match as many characters as it can.

You want them to instead match the minimal possible number of characters. To do that, change each `.*` into a `.*?`. The final question mark will make the pattern match the minimal number of characters. Because you anchor your pattern to a `]` character, it will still match/consume the whole link correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is greedy: it matches as many characters as it can, e.g. up to the last right parenthesis in your document. (After all, `.` means "any character" and `)` is 'any character" as much as any other character.)

You need the non-greedy version of `*`, which is `*?`. (Probably actually you should use `+?`, as I don't think zero-length matches would be very useful).